# Tikz: Problem with foreach loop and math in list

Tags: tikz-pgf, foreach

I copied the following tikz code (indicating a magnetic field) from the source code of a document I created some years ago (and which compiled at that time). Now it doesn't compile anymore. Here is a MWE with the relevant code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\usetikzlibrary{shapes.misc}

\tikzset{cross/.style={cross out, draw=black, minimum size=2*(#1-\pgflinewidth), inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt},cross/.default={1pt}}

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\a}{1.25}

\foreach \x in {-\a,...,3*\a} { 
\foreach \y in {-1.3*\a,0,1.3*\a}{
\draw(\x,\y) circle (5pt);%
\draw[thick] (\x,\y) node[cross=3.8pt] {};%
}}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Errors:

```
 foreach.tex                 21 Error   Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
 foreach.tex                 21 Error   Missing = inserted for \ifdim.
 foreach.tex                 21 Error   Missing number, treated as zero.
 foreach.tex                 21 Error   Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
 foreach.tex                 21 Error   Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted).
```

What did I wrong and how can I fix it? Did the code change for calculations in foreach loops over time?

Here is how the original picture looked like (I omitted the code for the induction loop in the above MEW, included just the magnetic field).

[image]

Comment: If you have math in the `\foreach` list, you should use the option `parse`: `\foreach [parse=true] \x in {-\a,...,3*\a} {` ...

Comment: Thanks. That solves the problem. Do you know if I can set the option `parse=true` globally? If so, does it have any side effects? Was `parse=true` default some years ago?

Comment: @Julia The [`parse` key](https://tikz.dev/pgffor#pgf/foreach/parse) is in the namespace `/pgf/foreach`. So either `\pgfkeys{/pgf/foreach/parse=true}`, `\tikzset{/pgf/foreach/parse=true}` (`[/pgf/foreach/parse=true]` as an option to a TikZ picture, scope or a path) or `\pgfset{foreach/parse=true}` should do. Side effect: It adds overhead since it evaluated every (and only the) last item in a list, even if it wouldn't have to and it will likely break when you dont loop over PGFmath-y content.